# Creating vector joining two geopositions

Tags: vector

I have two points in Lat, Long, Elevation format. I need to find vector/direction joining them.

Would I need to convert them both to ECEF coordinates first?

Comment: It really depends on how far apart your points are and how much inaccuracy you're prepared to accept. What language/API do you have to work with? Do you have any code currently? If you do a google search for *geodesic distance bearing* you will find links like https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html which should be fairly close to accurate.

Comment: Actually they are very very close. They represent end points of a road sign structure, like a hoarding or speed sign. I am using scala with in-house geospatial libraries.

Comment: If they are very close you shouldn't need to use geodesic methods unless a milimetre or two is going to be problematic. Do you need the vector in feet/metres? I would suggest projecting both points to UTM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system, have a look at https://github.com/geotrellis/gdal-scala, although I know nothing of Java and Scala I do know GDAL with OSR which will easily convert two point classes to a nominated UTM projection making a displacement vector in metres easy to calculate.